# How to do Asynchrone Events in Asp.Net MVC WebApi

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, events, model-view-controller

My API in asp.net MVC WebApi have serveral slowness when I execute some functionality.
It's because my functionality do many things in synchro way.

Exemple : 
functionality for create User :

- format user
- add in bdd
- send mail (take time)
- create some other entity (take    time)
- Response 200 to the client

I would like something like that

- format user
- add in bdd
- create event for send mail
- create event to create other entity
- Response 200 to the client
- send mail (take time)
- create some other entity (take    time)

I heard about EventBus or something like that but i don't find a complete answer

thanks for the help!!

Comment: Are you running .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code with the issue (slowness), then explain what you have tried (with EventBus or something else) to make the code asynchronous.

Comment: MVC WebApi is .Net Framework, the code is not important because i dont search for a code particulary but several things that look like that technicaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .NET Framework, there is integrated functionality you can use: the [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.1#overloads) method.

> Schedules a task which can run in the background, independent of any request.

For .NET Core, there is an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/805) open to ship this functionality as well, but currently there is no functionality like this out of the box. The recommended approach is implementing a [`BackgroundTaskQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) using dependency injection.

I haven't personally used this, but you could also try using a library like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).